# Creating a HTML table from the simplest PHP array

Tags: html, arrays, loops

I am starting to learn basics of PHP programming
language and my  question  is how to create a HTML table containing 10 rows, 10 cols from an regular array:

```
$array = array(0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99, 100);
```

Maybe we can use here both for and foreach loops?

Comment: Hi Demeter, welcome on board. SO is not a place to learn :) it's a place to ask questions and get help from fellow developers when you face a problem. So I suggest you to first try some online tutorials, try them, and if you find any problems,  come back and ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<table><tr><th>....';
foreach($arr as $o){
  echo >>>EOTR
<tr>
  <td>{$o->logtime}</td>
  <td>{$o->useragent}</td>
  <td>{$o->remotehost}</td>
  <td>{$o->page}</td>
  <td>{$o->action}</td>
</tr>
EOTR;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Try something like this.

Comment: Thanks for upvote. If it helped you, kindly accept this as answer.

Comment: Dear Ananya, thanks for trying to answer my question. I'll check it in an interpreter and will answer if it works or not. Demeter.